Which map type to choose when creating a map ID in Google Maps plaform for a Flutter Project?
I'm currently working on a Flutter project where I want to implement cloud-based map styling using the cloudMapId parameter provided by the google_maps_flutter package.
When I try to create a new Map ID in the Google Cloud Console, I'm prompted to select a 'Map type' with the following options: JavaScript, Android, iOS, and Static.

I’m unsure which option I should choose for my Flutter project. Does the choice of map type impact the functionality or interactivity of the map within the Flutter app? Is there a recommended option specifically for Flutter projects?

I think you might need to create two map types, one for Android and one for iOS and in your logic in Flutter, identify the current OS and use the relevant map id.

In most cases, if you're targeting both platforms, you'll need to create two map IDs—one for Android and one for iOS. If you're only developing for Android or iOS, select the corresponding option.
